auth: HttpTimeoutError: Request to <https://api.github.com/copilot_internal/v2/token> timed out after 120000ms
I am using github copilot with the vscode remote-ssh extension on a RedHat 9.4 Server. Unfortunately the github copilot extension fails authenticate with api.github.com. (curl to the url is possible).
When I sign out and sign in again, the Github-Copilot-Icon in the toolbar seems to look fine and also the Status says "ready" but it still doesnt work.
Here is the log-output of GitHub Copilot:
2024-11-21 10:37:52.443 [error] [auth] auth: HttpTimeoutError: Request to <https://api.github.com/copilot_internal/v2/token> timed out after 120000ms
    at /home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:95:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at pue.fetch (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:93:22)
    ... 5 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at attemptAuthentication (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/extension/src/auth.ts:58:9) {
  cause: FetchError: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read ETIMEDOUT
      at fetch (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:99:11)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at cachingFetch (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:288:16)
      at pue.fetch (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:93:22)
      at fetchCopilotToken (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/lib/src/auth/copilotToken.ts:195:16)
      at authFromGitHubToken (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/lib/src/auth/copilotToken.ts:128:22)
      at auth (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/extension/src/auth.ts:40:25)
      at authShowWarnings (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/extension/src/auth.ts:131:25)
      at oae.getCopilotToken (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/extension/src/auth.ts:174:33)
      at attemptAuthentication (/home/nwmadm/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.245.0/extension/src/auth.ts:58:9) {
    type: 'system',
    _name: 'FetchError',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    errno: -110,
    erroredSysCall: 'read'
  }
}
2024-11-21 10:37:52.443 [error] [auth] Request to <https://api.github.com/copilot_internal/v2/token> timed out after 120000ms

I already deleted the .vscode-server Folder and reinstalled everything from scratch. Also, on a Redhat 7.9 server it works. There is no proxy involved. Any advice what else I could try would be very welcome. Thanks in advance!

if possible, please do Ctrl Shift P > GitHub Copilot Diagnostic and attach the log to your post. We can help you troubleshoot on that faster
